# How to compare case sensitive string in EF?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership

the Membership Provider `ValidateUser` using EF is quite simple

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    // Validate User Credentials
    var r = db.ST_Users.FirstOrDefault(
                           x => x.Username.Equals(username) && 
                                x.Password.Equals(password));
    return r != null ? true : false;
}
```

But this returns `true` (finds and retrieves the hole object) no matter if I use `balexandre` or `BAleXanDre`.

> **How can I enable EF to compare in case-sensitive mode?**

I know how to compare in case insensitive (using the `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` overload, but I just want the opposite)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not query on the password. You should retrieve the `User` object and do a password compare locally, because SQL server will do a case insensitive compare for you by default (unless you change your database settings, which is not something you should take lightly).

```
var r = db.ST_Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

return r != null && r.Password == password;
```

Besides, you seem to be storing plain passwords in your database. Depending on the type of application, this might not be a good idea. Try hashing them with a salt. Lots of good information to find about that here on Stackoverflow. For instance, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948994/which-of-the-net-included-hashing-algoritms-are-secure-enough-for-pasword-hashi) and [this website](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: The +1 is for both the answer and advice. Learn from Sony, ECI, and all the other companies that have made the news as of late - DO NOT store plain text passwords!

Comment: I use `BCrypt` to store my passwords, the question only has a plain example. Would be weird that with my reputation I wouldn't know/store sensitive data the correct way!

Comment: @balexandre: I'm not familiar to `BCrypt`, but if you are storing your passwords in a hashed form in the database, you wont have any string insensitive string compare problem, so it seems to me that you are not storing your passwords in a hashed form. Perhaps you are encrypting your passwords, which is less safe than hashing. Besides why do you want to be able to decrypt your users passwords?

Comment: the question was just a plain example for other part of the application, that I can't (as it belongs to the company) put the code - weird internal rules. `BCrypt` is extremely easy to use and extremely safe >> http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx. Again, my question has only an example code, not production code. **But I got something from your answer**: Don't compare with LINQ, extract the object and compare outside the query. Thank's for that.

Comment: @balexandre: Don't shoot the messenger ;-) I'm glad my answer helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried:

```
1. from p in entity.SecurityUsers where p.userName.Equals(userName) && p.password.Equals(password) select p
2. from p in entity.SecurityUsers where p.userName == userName && p.password == password select p
```

But both of these didn't work. Then I selected `USER` only..,

```
var user = (from p in entity.SecurityUsers where p.userName == userName select p).first();
```

And then compare its password:

```
return p != null && p.Password == password;
```