# Which of the .NET included hashing algorithms are suitable for password hashing?

Tags: c#, .net, security, hash

The [password leak of LinkedIn](https://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002379.html) proved how important it is to securely hash your passwords. However, even hashing passwords with a salt is not secure with the 'normal' hashing algorithms (such as MD5 and the SHA family), since they are optimized for speed, which allows hackers compute 2300 million hashes per second (brute force).

There are hashing algoritms that are safer to use because they are much more computational intensive, such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [Bcrypt](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/), PBMAC, and [scrypt](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html). These hashing algorithms however, don't seem to be included in the .NET framework.

So, which performance intensive hashing algorithms are included in the .NET framework?

**ANSWER:** PBKDF2 is included in the framework and [this site shows how to use it properly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_Rfc2898DeriveBytes_for_PBKDF2).

Comment: Interesting question, I was wondering the same thing because of the same reasons. :)

Comment: Nothing is "Secure".  What you choose for security will always be a trade off with other requirements like speed, memory usage, CPU utilization, etc..  What you consider "secure enough" is based on *your* requirements--which you haven't provided.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: That's why I'm refering to "hashing algoritms that are safer to" and that's what the question is about.

Comment: @Steven  Decide what algorithm included in the .NET framework is currently most secure based on your criteria (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242648/what-is-the-most-secure-hashing-algorithm-in-the-net-framework ).  If that isn't secure enough for your requirements, decide which one that isn't included in .NET is most secure based on your criteria and either find a library that implements it, or implement it yourself.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie While I'm usually all with the 'roll your own' attitude; in the case of a hash function, or anything security related, I'd highly advise against unless you really know what you are doing. Just sayin' ;)

Comment: @cloud  yes, a very important criteria--which may mean that Rfc2898DeriveBytes might be your best choice.

Comment: Why is this question closed?  There are a finite number of hashing algorithms included in the .NET framework and their relative suitability to password hashing is fairly objective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's not really a meaningful Class name, but I do think it is included in the .NET framework. According to multiple sources, [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) is actually a PBKDF2 implementation. MSDN says so as well.

See 
[Why do I need to use the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class (in .NET) instead of directly using the password as a key or IV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly) 
and
[PBKDF2 implementation in C# with Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046599/pbkdf2-implementation-in-c-sharp-with-rfc2898derivebytes)

for example.

Answer (score 2):

There is also:

http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/ (bcrypt)

http://www.zer7.com/software.php?page=cryptsharp (scrypt, etc)

Answer (score -1):

There is no hashing algorith that is 100% secure. The linkedin hack was more due to infrastructure/code security than the hashing algorithm. Any hash can be calculated, it just takes longer the more complicated the hashing algortihm is. Some attacks such as collision attacks are not actually much slower to accomplish on a more complicated hash.

I always ensure that i hash passwords (never just encrypt), restrict access to servers. All developers workingfor me understand at least the basics of security (sql injection, overflows etc) and any high profile site i work on is pen-tested.

Comment: I don't think Steven is thinking that choosing a secure hashing algorithm will protect him from hacks. But it does protect him in the event that your DB access gets compromised. LinkedIn used SHA1 (!!) hashes without a salt (!!); that's unbelievably bad. Steven wants to pick a more secure algorithm and he is right to do so. Nothing is 100% secure obviously; you can only try to make it very unlikely that a hash will get brute forced in a feasible amount of time.

Comment: Well, I actually wanted to make my user list publicly accessible from the website and include the hashed passwords since nobody can decrypt them. No, of course not, just kidding :-P. @Cloud is absolutely right, but the fault is on me. I should have done a better job in describing in my question that I know this, but this is something that is so obvious for me, that it is easy to forget.

Comment: But attacking a decent hash compared to what linkedin did is more expensive by a factor of at least a billion.