# How to get values from a list<class>

Tags: c#, class

I have these classes, which i want to use it to login, to check if the email and password is the same, then it will redirect to the respective page.

```
public class Account
  {
    public Account(){}
    public int accID { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string mobileNo { get; set; }
    public string officeNo { get; set; }
   }
 public static SADataReader DoSelectQuery(String sql)
    {
        SAConnection myConnection = new SAConnection(DB_STR);
        //open the connection 
        myConnection.Open();
        //Create a command object. 
        SACommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();

        //Specify a query. 
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;

        //Create a DataReader for the command 
        SADataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        return reader;
    }
 public static List<Account> getAllAccountFromReader(SADataReader reader){
        List<Account> results = new List<Account>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int accID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string emailAddress = reader.GetString(1);
            string password = reader.GetString(2);
            string name = reader.GetString(3);
            string company = reader.GetString(4);
            string position = reader.GetString(5);
            string department = reader.GetString(6);
            string mobileNo = reader.GetString(7);
            string officeNo = reader.GetString(8);


            Account Accounts = new Account();
            Accounts.accID = accID;
            Accounts.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            Accounts.password = password;
            Accounts.name = name;
            Accounts.company = company;
            Accounts.position = position;
            Accounts.department = department;
            Accounts.mobileNo = mobileNo;
            Accounts.officeNo = officeNo;
            results.Add(Accounts);
        }
        return results;
    }
 public static List<Account> getAllAccounts()
    {
        //Specify a query. 
        string sql = "SELECT accountID,emailAddress,password,name,company,position,department,mobileNo,officeNo FROM account";

        SADataReader reader = DoSelectQuery(sql);
        List<Account> results = getAllAccountFromReader(reader);
        return results;
  }
```

.CS file to check for fields

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = tbEmail.Text;
        string password = tbPW.Text;
        List<Account> getAccounts = MinuteDB.getAllAccounts();

       // Session["getAllAccount"] = getAccounts;

      if(email ==?? && password == ??)
            {

                       //Session["name"] = name.ToString();
                       //Session["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(accID.ToString());
                      Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
            }

            else if (email == "" && password == "")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "error", "alert('Please enter Login and Password!');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "error", "alert('Wrong Login Or Password!');", true);
            }

    }
```

How do i retrieve the email and password from the List getAccounts so that i can check for if (email == *email from the list account* && password == *password from list account*) ??

Comment: Please don't store passwords.

Comment: Yep, but its a small project anyway.. i just want to get the field and compare it with the textboxes.

Comment: Even for a small project, don't do it. At least hash them, and while you're hashing them, add a salt to it. And if you don't know which hashing algorithm you need to use, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948994/secure-hashing-in-net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LINQ/extension methods.

```
var account = MinuteDB.getAllAccounts()
               .Where(p=> p.emailAddress==email && p.password==password)
               .FirstOrDefault();


if(account!=null)
{
  Session["id"]=account.accID;
  Session["name"]=account.name;
  Response.Redirect("~/other_page.aspx");
}
```

Write following code in `other_page.aspx` to read session key-value.

```
int id=0;
string name="";
if(Session["id"]!=null)
   id=int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString());
if(Session["name"]!=null)
   name=Session["name"];
```

PS: Do not store *password* in the `List<T>`. You may assign `Account` object reference to the Session.

e.g

```
 if(account!=null)
    {
      Session["account"]=account;
      Response.Redirect("~/other_page.aspx");
    }
```

and to retrieve the `account` value from session:

```
Account account=Session["account"] as Account;
if(account!=null)
 {
   //read the property value of Account
 }
```

Comment: Hey AVD, now I want to make retrieve the ID and name, so that i can display the name on another page, and that i can use the ID to retrieve the specific things that i want from the Database, how should i do it?? I know there is a way to do it using session, but I don't know how to store the whole session from the login and redirect to another page, and display the name and keep the ID on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to find the email in the list of accounts and check the password entered matches? If so, superficially you just loop through each along the lines of:

```
private bool isPasswordValid(string email, string password)
{
  foreach (Account account in Accounts)
  {
    if (account.emailAddress != email)
      continue;
    return (account.password == password);
  }
  return false;
}
```

You could alternatively return a `Dictionary<string, Account>` to simplify and speed up the search.

**Update**

So instead of the following line:

```
  if(email ==?? && password == ??)
```

Insert

```
 if (isPasswordValid(email, password))
   // it is valid
 else
   // it is not valid, redirect
```

This assumes the getAccounts variable is accessible to isPasswordValid. In your current code it would not be visible, so you might want to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it but er.. i just want to retrieve all the properties, eg : accID,email,password,etc from the List<Account> which have been made, and from that List<Account>, get the email and password values, and compare it to the textbox. If the textbox value is the same as the one gotten, then it will redirect.