# How to encrypt/decrypt for storage of sensitive data (ASP.NET Web API project)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption-symmetric

I am currently developping a web service. As part of this web service, I am be able to securely store user password in a SQL DB, and be able to unencrypt password value to the end-user through HTTPS web service.

It's the first time I have to deal with this requirement. I found many example based on symetric and/or asymetric encryption. However I don't understand to permanently store the password/key used to encrypt the data.

For instance, if I do use a symetric encryption based on RijndaelManaged, how do I securely store the input parameters used for the encryption so that my web service can at a later time retrieve data for the SQL DB, and unencrypt them.

Comment: Encryption and security are very difficult topics and you really should make sure you understand the topics properly before trying to implement anything yourself. At least if this is meant to be used in production! :-)

Answer (score 3):

> securely store user password in a SQL DB, and be able to unencrypt
>   password value

That's not secure. Passwords should never be encrypted; they should be ***hashed***! With a salt and a [hashing algorithm that is suited for pashword hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948994/secure-hashing-in-net).

Comment: Generally speaking, of course I would agree with you. But you can see my application as a password management storage service... I need to let user store password... and retrieve them As such a case, hash is not an option.

Comment: There *must* be a secret component and it's not secret if it's on the same machine (regardless what you think). If you're making a password storage service you have an account password and stored passwords. If you use the plaintext account password to encrypt stored passwords and only store the hash of account passwords you should be fine.

Comment: I to have gone through this method far better more secure results so theyare

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
public class Crypto
{
        #region enums, constants & fields
        //types of symmetric encyption
        public enum CryptoTypes
        {
            encTypeDES = 0,
            encTypeRC2,
            encTypeRijndael,
            encTypeTripleDES
        }

    private const string CRYPT_DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "yourDefaultPassword"; //"CB06cfE507a1";
    private const CryptoTypes CRYPT_DEFAULT_METHOD = CryptoTypes.encTypeRijndael;

    private byte[] mKey = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24};
    private byte[] mIV = {65, 110, 68, 26, 69, 178, 200, 219};
    private byte[] SaltByteArray  = {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
    private CryptoTypes mCryptoType = CRYPT_DEFAULT_METHOD;
    private string mPassword = CRYPT_DEFAULT_PASSWORD;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public Crypto()
    {
        calculateNewKeyAndIV();
    }

    public Crypto(CryptoTypes CryptoType)
    {
        this.CryptoType = CryptoType;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Props

    /// <summary>
    ///     type of encryption / decryption used
    /// </summary>
    public CryptoTypes CryptoType
    {
        get
        {
            return mCryptoType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mCryptoType != value)
            {
                mCryptoType = value;
                calculateNewKeyAndIV();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Passsword Key Property.
    ///     The password key used when encrypting / decrypting
    /// </summary>
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return mPassword;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mPassword != value)
            {
                mPassword = value;
                calculateNewKeyAndIV();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Encryption

    /// <summary>
    ///     Encrypt a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">text to encrypt</param>
    /// <returns>an encrypted string</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string inputText)
    {
        //declare a new encoder
        UTF8Encoding UTF8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        //get byte representation of string
        byte[] inputBytes = UTF8Encoder.GetBytes(inputText);

        //convert back to a string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptDecrypt(inputBytes,true));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Encrypt string with user defined password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="password">password to use when encrypting</param>
    /// <returns>an encrypted string</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string inputText, string password)
    {
        this.Password = password;
        return this.Encrypt(inputText);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Encrypt string acc. to cryptoType and with user defined password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="password">password to use when encrypting</param>
    /// <param storeName="cryptoType">type of encryption</param>
    /// <returns>an encrypted string</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string inputText, string password, CryptoTypes cryptoType)
    {
        mCryptoType = cryptoType;
        return this.Encrypt(inputText,password);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Encrypt string acc. to cryptoType
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="cryptoType">type of encryption</param>
    /// <returns>an encrypted string</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string inputText, CryptoTypes cryptoType)
    {
        this.CryptoType = cryptoType;
        return this.Encrypt(inputText);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Decryption

    /// <summary>
    ///     decrypts a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">string to decrypt</param>
    /// <returns>a decrypted string</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string inputText)
    {
        //declare a new encoder
        UTF8Encoding UTF8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        //get byte representation of string
        byte[] inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);

        //convert back to a string
        return UTF8Encoder.GetString(EncryptDecrypt(inputBytes,false));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     decrypts a string using a user defined password key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">string to decrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="password">password to use when decrypting</param>
    /// <returns>a decrypted string</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string inputText, string password)
    {
        this.Password = password;
        return Decrypt(inputText);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     decrypts a string acc. to decryption type and user defined password key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">string to decrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="password">password key used to decrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="cryptoType">type of decryption</param>
    /// <returns>a decrypted string</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string inputText, string password, CryptoTypes cryptoType)
    {
        mCryptoType = cryptoType;
        return Decrypt(inputText,password);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     decrypts a string acc. to the decryption type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">string to decrypt</param>
    /// <param storeName="cryptoType">type of decryption</param>
    /// <returns>a decrypted string</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string inputText, CryptoTypes cryptoType)
    {
        this.CryptoType = cryptoType;
        return Decrypt(inputText);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Symmetric Engine

    /// <summary>
    ///     performs the actual enc/dec.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputBytes">input byte array</param>
    /// <param storeName="Encrpyt">wheather or not to perform enc/dec</param>
    /// <returns>byte array output</returns>
    private byte[] EncryptDecrypt(byte[] inputBytes, bool Encrpyt)
    {
        //get the correct transform
        ICryptoTransform transform = getCryptoTransform(Encrpyt);

        //memory stream for output
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            //setup the cryption - output written to memstream
            CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream,transform,CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            //write data to cryption engine
            cryptStream.Write(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length);

            //we are finished
            cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            //get result
            byte[] output = memStream.ToArray();

            //finished with engine, so close the stream
            cryptStream.Close();

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //throw an error
            throw new Exception("Error in symmetric engine. Error : " + e.Message,e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     returns the symmetric engine and creates the encyptor/decryptor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="encrypt">whether to return a encrpytor or decryptor</param>
    /// <returns>ICryptoTransform</returns>
    private ICryptoTransform getCryptoTransform(bool encrypt)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm SA = selectAlgorithm();
        SA.Key = mKey;
        SA.IV = mIV;
        if (encrypt)
        {
            return SA.CreateEncryptor();
        }else
        {
            return SA.CreateDecryptor();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     returns the specific symmetric algorithm acc. to the cryptotype
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>SymmetricAlgorithm</returns>
    private SymmetricAlgorithm selectAlgorithm()
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm SA;
        switch (mCryptoType)
        {
            case CryptoTypes.encTypeDES:
                SA = DES.Create();
                break;
            case CryptoTypes.encTypeRC2:
                SA = RC2.Create();
                break;
            case CryptoTypes.encTypeRijndael:
                SA = Rijndael.Create();
                break;
            case CryptoTypes.encTypeTripleDES:
                SA = TripleDES.Create();
                break;
            default:
                SA = TripleDES.Create();
                break;
        }
        return SA;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     calculates the key and IV acc. to the symmetric method from the password
    ///     key and IV size dependant on symmetric method
    /// </summary>
    private void calculateNewKeyAndIV()
    {
        //use salt so that key cannot be found with dictionary attack
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(mPassword,SaltByteArray);
        SymmetricAlgorithm algo = selectAlgorithm();
        mKey = pdb.GetBytes(algo.KeySize / 8);
        mIV = pdb.GetBytes(algo.BlockSize / 8);
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Hashing class. Only static members so no need to create an instance
/// </summary>
public class Hashing
{
    #region enum, constants and fields
    //types of hashing available
    public enum HashingTypes
    {
        SHA, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, MD5
    }
    #endregion

    #region static members
    public static string Hash(String inputText)
    {
        return ComputeHash(inputText,HashingTypes.MD5);
    }

    public static string Hash(String inputText, HashingTypes hashingType)
    {
        return ComputeHash(inputText,hashingType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     returns true if the input text is equal to hashed text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">unhashed text to test</param>
    /// <param storeName="hashText">already hashed text</param>
    /// <returns>boolean true or false</returns>
    public static bool isHashEqual(string inputText, string hashText)
    {
        return (Hash(inputText) == hashText);
    }

    public static bool isHashEqual(string inputText, string hashText, HashingTypes hashingType)
    {
        return (Hash(inputText,hashingType) == hashText);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Hashing Engine

    /// <summary>
    ///     computes the hash code and converts it to string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="inputText">input text to be hashed</param>
    /// <param storeName="hashingType">type of hashing to use</param>
    /// <returns>hashed string</returns>
    private static string ComputeHash(string inputText, HashingTypes hashingType)
    {
        HashAlgorithm HA = getHashAlgorithm(hashingType);

        //declare a new encoder
        UTF8Encoding UTF8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        //get byte representation of input text
        byte[] inputBytes = UTF8Encoder.GetBytes(inputText);


        //hash the input byte array
        byte[] output = HA.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        //convert output byte array to a string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(output);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     returns the specific hashing alorithm
    /// </summary>
    /// <param storeName="hashingType">type of hashing to use</param>
    /// <returns>HashAlgorithm</returns>
    private static HashAlgorithm getHashAlgorithm(HashingTypes hashingType)
    {
        switch (hashingType)
        {
            case HashingTypes.MD5 :
                return new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            case HashingTypes.SHA :
                return new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            case HashingTypes.SHA256 :
                return new SHA256Managed();
            case HashingTypes.SHA384 :
                return new SHA384Managed();
            case HashingTypes.SHA512 :
                return new SHA512Managed();
            default :
                return new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

You can use **Encrypt** and **Decrypt** methods for encryption and decryption

I used this on my projects...

Comment: If you use this, make sure to change the IV and Salt to different values!