# check whether there is already a record in the database (LinqToSql, vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I need some help at inserting my data (username and password) into a mssql database.
with linq to sql this is my solution but at the -> marked line I always get an EntityCommandExecutionException. I have a html website with two textboxes where I get the String out of and send the request via javascript - ajax to vb.net.

I'm doing research now for a long time and i can't find any solution.

As you can see I want to check if there is a datarow with this username but it doesn't work in the situation when there is no datarow in the table. That means the query should be 'NULL' or am I wrong?

```
Public Shared Function addData(ByVal username As String, ByVal passwort As String)

    Dim db = New LoginContext
    Dim benutzer = New Benutzer
    Dim available As Boolean = False
    Dim sha As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

    Dim vName = (_
        From b In db.BenutzerSet 
        Where b.Name = username.ToLower() 
        Select b)

  ->  If vName.Count() = 0 Or vName Is Nothing Then
        benutzer.Name = username.ToLower()

        Dim bytesToHash() As Byte

        bytesToHash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwort)

        bytesToHash = sha.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

        Dim encPassword As String = ""

        For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
            encPassword += b.ToString("x2")
        Next

        benutzer.Passwort = encPassword
        db.BenutzerSet.Add(benutzer)
        db.SaveChanges()
        available = True
    Else
        available = False
    End If
    Return available
End Function
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the exact exception? Please add the exception message and stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vName.Any()` to check if there are any records in your Query!

```
->  If vName.Any() = false Then
```

also change `Dim benutzer = New Benutzer` to `Dim benutzer As New Benutzer`

Comment: Thanks but how do I have to correct my code

If vName.Count() = 0 Or vName Is Nothing Then

If vName.Count() = 0 Or vName.Any() Is Nothing Then
I need to go forward if there is no such a user with this username or in this case when the table is still empty (no users)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer to your question, but here's some feedback:

1. The check `vName.Count() = 0 Or vName Is Nothing` is in the wrong order since VB executes them from left to right. If `vName` is actually Nothing, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`, since `vName.Count()` is executed first.
2. LINQ operators (such as `Where` and `Select`) will actually never return `Nothing`, so you don't have to check `vName Is Nothing`; it is redundant.
3. Using `vName.Any()` has the same result as `vName.Count() == 0`, but is more readable, and results most of the time in a more efficient SQL query.
4. Very good that you are hashing your passwords. But to be safe, you should add a salt [and don't use SHA as a hashing algoritm for storing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948994).

Comment: I'm a bit late but thanks for your answer, I'll make some of these changes which I haven't implemented yet!